# mediaplayer and service class

Tags: java, android, service, media-player, android-mediaplayer

i have a service class that run my mediaplayer it works fine, my only problem is that when my service create the mediaplayer it somewhat pause my UI like its hangs or something until my mediaplayer is done creating it self. what i want to happened is that when I press playbutton a toast message appears and display "Connecting" and when the mediaplayer is prepared displays a toast message says "Connected" then mediaplayer starts to play the music somehow my toast are not displaying and if they do its late..

heres my service code:

```
public class myservice extends Service {

MediaPlayer player;
private Handler UIHandler = new Handler();
private Uri source = Uri.parse("http://www.mydomain.com:8000/listen.mp3");

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Connecting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            player = MediaPlayer.create(this, source);
}

private void testtoast() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Connecting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void onStart(Intent intent, int StartId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    player.setOnPreparedListener( new OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer player) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            player.start();
        }
    });
}

public void onDestroy() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    player.stop();
    player.release();
}
  }
```

Comment: I have personally never used the `MediaPlayer` class so I don't know anything about using it or how it behaves when you `.create()` it. However, I thought it's worth pointing out that a `Service` runs within the UI thread, *not* within its own separate thread or process. This means that any time-consuming work that you perform within the `Service`, such as in `onCreate()`, will therefore affect the responsiveness of your UI and even cause an ANR if you're not careful. Therefore, any time-consuming or process-intensive work you do within a `Service` should still be done on a separate `Thread`.

Comment: thank for pointing that out trevor do you have a sample on how can i do that.. im a noob in android really

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
      player = MediaPlayer.create(this, source);
```

with

```
      player = new MediaPlayer();
      player.setDataSource(source);
      player.prepareAsync();
```

`MediaPlayer.create` calls `prepare()` method to prepare MediaPlayer which is a synchronous operation and hangs the UI so you will experience a delay in your UI.  So you should use `.prepareAsync()` explicitly to avoid this delay as provided in example above.